# Uploading images on Android to Firebase storage using expo-image-picker and expo-image-manipulator extremly poor image quality

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload images on Android to Firebase storage using expo-image-picker and expo-image-manipulator but when they are uploaded to Firebase they come out extremally pixelated, and the color is way off. Everything works well on iOS and on a Android simulator. I'm not sure why only physical Android devices have this problem. Here is my code:

```
 const handlePickImage = async () => {
    if (hasCameraRollPermission) {
      try {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 3],
          quality: 1,
        });

        if (!result.cancelled) {
          handleUploadImage(result.uri);
        } else {
          alert(
            "Error"
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Please enable camera roll permissions in your settings.");
    }
  };



const handleUploadImage = async (uri) => {

    const resizedPhoto = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      uri,
      [{ resize: { width: 750 } }],
      { }
    );

    const thumbnail = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      uri,
      [{ resize: { width: 70, height: 70 } }],
      {}
    );

    const card = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      uri,
      [{ resize: { width: 175, height: 170 } }],
      {}
    );

    const storage = getStorage();
    const uploadUri = `redacted`;
    const reference = ref(storage, uploadUri);

    const img = await fetch(resizedPhoto.uri);

    const bytes = await img.blob();

    const result = await uploadBytes(reference, bytes);

    const url = await getDownloadURL(result.ref);
```

I've tried changing the compression, and quality without any success. Again this only has the issue with physical Android devices.